# Flutter HTTP server - serve flutter web in another app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http, web

I have created two Flutter applications. The first is Android app and contains an HTTP server that I want to use to serve this application via a web page. The second is Flutter web application. I built the second application and thanks to that I got files like index.html, main.dart.js and others. I would like to add these files to the first application so that when the HTTP server is turned on and the correct web page is loaded with the appropriate IP and port, this second application will be displayed. Is this possible? I have added these files to the assets folder, I have also added them to pubspec.yaml. I created a function that reads the index.html and sends it to the client using request.response.write.

[image: assets folder]

```
Future<void> showWeb(HttpRequest request) async {
  String _content = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/web/index.html');
  request.response
    ..statusCode = HttpStatus.ok
    ..headers.set("Content-Type", "application/javascript; charset=utf-8")
    ..write(_content)
    ..close();
}
```

I put "text/html" as the header, which throws me an error "content type mismatch". When I add "application/javascript" as a header, I get the source code of the html file.

Is it possible to view the Flutter web app using an HTTP server?

Comment: `Is it possible to view the Flutter web app using an HTTP server?` I do not understand that question. Your http server serves a html file from assets. You can check if your server does its job from any browser on that device or any browser on devices in the same network.

Comment: @blackapps I tried to upload the web application to Firebase, where it loads normally. But I would like the user of the application to just tap the http server in the application and the web browser on the localhost with the given port will display the web application. I don't want to write html and css, I want to create a Flutter web application and put the generated files (html, etc) into the first application that displays them on the given port.

Comment: That can all be. But is it relevant for the problem you encountered? It seems that serving a html page goes wrong. To test if your server works you can start with a simple html page.

Comment: `put the generated files (html, etc) into the first application that displays them on the given port.` I cannot follow you. The first application serves those files. It will display nothing. The browser displays.

Comment: @blackapps That worked too. I added an html file where I only added the title and text to the body to test that it worked. Then I tried adding the generated html file. It reported to me that I was missing main.dart.js. So I added it to the folder as well. It didn't work. So I added the whole generated folder, but that didn't work either. And as I wrote, when I put text/html as header, it says content type mismatch and when application/javascript, it only shows the source code. I'm doing something wrong

Comment: `. It reported to me that I was missing main.dart.js.` Who reported that?

Comment: @blackapps console in the browser

Comment: How does your server receive the request for the .js file? I hope you do some logging. The server should have responded with a 404 page not found before the console can say such nasty things.

Comment: Try with your simple html file where you include a .js file.

Comment: @blackapps same problem. Probably my content-type is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I came back to this project and came up with a solution to my problem. Maybe it will help someone.

1. Build the Flutter web application and copy the /build/web folder.
2. In the second application, create an "assets" folder and paste the following folder into it
3. Put the following paths into pubspec.yaml (you may have more, it's up to your check, but this is the default):

```
    - assets/web/
    - assets/web/assets/
    - assets/web/assets/fonts/
    - assets/web/assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/
    - assets/web/assets/shaders/
    - assets/web/canvaskit/
    - assets/web/canvaskit/profiling/
    - assets/web/icons/
```

4. Create a function to handle a get request

```
void handleGet(HttpRequest request) async {
  final path = request.uri.path;
  String _content;
  Uint8List _contentByte;
  String _mimeType;
  bool isItByte;
  try {
    isItByte = false;
    if (path == '/') {
      _content = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/web/index.html');
      _mimeType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
    } else {
      var dotoffset = path.lastIndexOf('.');
      if (path.substring(dotoffset) == '.png' ||
          path.substring(dotoffset) == '.ttf' ||
          path.substring(dotoffset) == '.otf') {
        _contentByte = await File('assets/web' + path.toString()).readAsBytes();
        isItByte = true;
      } else {
        _content = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/web' + path.toString());
      }

      _mimeType = dotoffset == -1
          ? 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
          : {
              '.html': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
              '.css': 'text/css; charset=utf-8',
              '.js': 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8',
              '.csv': 'text/csv; charset=utf-8',
              '.txt': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
              '.ico': 'image/x-icon',
              '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
              '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
              '.png': 'image/png',
              '.gif': 'image/gif',
              '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
              '.json': 'application/json',
              '.xml': 'application/xml',
              '.ttf': 'font/ttf',
              '.otf': 'font/otf'
            }[path.substring(dotoffset)];
    }
    if (isItByte) {
      request.response
        ..statusCode = HttpStatus.ok
        ..headers.set("Content-Type", _mimeType)
        ..write(_contentByte)
        ..close();
    } else {
      request.response
        ..statusCode = HttpStatus.ok
        ..headers.set("Content-Type", _mimeType)
        ..write(_content)
        ..close();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

It is necessary that both applications have the same font and then everything works.

The code is not optimized, I'm still working on it, but it's enough for an illustration.

Comment: The png/ttf/otf branch of this does not work - in two ways.
First, File(....) doesn't read relative to assets/ so it can't find the path
Second, the bytes served in that case are not handled correctly by the web viewer.

Comment: Okay, so I have to use function rootBundle.load(<pathToAssets>).asStream()?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's the correct approach, but I had issues getting it to work - even when it read the correct bytes it appeared to serve them improperly, but I didn't spend a lot of time on it.